# Trouble with Java's Vector's and JTable

Tags: java, vector, jtable, classcastexception

I'm tinkering with JTables and Vectors for the first time in Java, and I've hit an interesting snag. My code compiles correctly, but when I go to run it, I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Vector

I don't see anywhere where I'm casting, so I'm a bit confused.

```
Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
columnNames.add("Tasks");

Vector<String> testing = new Vector<String>();
testing.add("one");
testing.add("two");
testing.add("three");

table = new JTable(testing, columnNames); // Line where the error occurrs.
scrollingArea = new JScrollPane(table);
```

My goal is to have a table of JPanels, but I have the same type of error when I try to use a Vector of < taskPanel > Here's the class that extends JPanel:

```
class taskPanel extends JPanel
{
    JLabel repeat, command, timeout, useGD;

    public taskPanel()
    {
        repeat = new JLabel("Repeat:");
        command = new JLabel("Command:");
        timeout = new JLabel("Timeout:");
        useGD = new JLabel("Update Google Docs:");

        add(repeat);
        add(command);
        add(timeout);
        add(useGD);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show full code and exact exception with stack trace? Personally I have doubt this is the line you have problem with..

Comment: This question something related to the following link

[Vector Example<String>][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111745/how-to-create-an-array-of-string-vectors-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `Vector` of `Vectors` here:

```
Vector<Vector> rowData = new Vector<Vector>();
rowData.addElement(testing);

JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
```

For a multi-column `Vector` table model, see this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/publicJTableVectorrowDataVectorcolumnNames.htm).

Comment: You can have a Vector<Vector<String>>. Your problem is that you're passing a one-dimensional structure when you need a two-dimensional structure.

Comment: This is not a problem. Each entry of the outer `Vector` is the row data. Each entry in the inner `Vector` is the column data which can have as many columns as required.

Comment: @reimeus Sorry, my comment was poorly worded. I wasn't disagreeing with anything Reimeus said. There was just a comment somewhere in here about a problem with Vector<String>, and I was trying to say that you can readily add the <String> part to Reimeus solution, you just have to have Vector<Vector<String>>, not just Vector<String>.

Answer (score 3):

Your `testing` vector should be `vector of vectors` as each row is supposed to contain data for all columns e.g.

```
    Vector<Vector> testing = new Vector<Vector>();
    Vector<String> rowOne = new Vector<String>();
    rowOne.add("one");
    Vector<String> rowTwo = new Vector<String>();
    rowTwo.add("two");
    Vector<String> rowThree = new Vector<String>();
    rowThree.add("three");

    testing.add(rowOne);
    testing.add(rowTwo);
    testing.add(rowThree);

    table = new JTable(testing, columnNames); // should work now
    scrollingArea = new JScrollPane(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

The casting is the < String >. You can't have Vector Strings at the moment. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111745/how-to-create-an-array-of-string-vectors-).